# Can't run perl-browser

Tags: perl

I'm trying to run this program [perl-browser](http://trizen.go.ro/) but I'm getting fowllowing error:

```
$ perl ./perl-browser
Can't locate Gtk2/WebKit.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.10 /usr/share/perl/5.10 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at ./perl-browser line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./perl-browser line 8.
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like module webkit is not installed. I think you should try something like this (or google perl modules installation)

```
sudo apt-get install cpanminus libwebkitgtk-devel
sudo cpanm Gtk2::WebKit
```

Hope it will work.